# Fast multipole method: help on tutorial

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I have some hard time with the FMM (Fast multipole method). I try to understand the basics with: "http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/labs/cvl/pirl/vikas/publications/FMM_tutorial.pdf".
So here are my questions:

1. [Solved: we need to think locally in order to not include source point inside the sphere] p7: why the middleman method only work for regular potential ? (and not for singular ones)

[image]

2. [Solved: we need accuracy too] p7 what is the interest in multiple center ? We can easily see on that the figure (b) is simpler that the (c)! One center seem to give less calculus wich 
   is the objective
   [image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCM2X.png)
3. What does :S-expansion and R-expansion stand for ? Is it "Regular-Expansion" and "Singular-Expansion" ?

4.[Solved]I don't understand the graphic. Why the branch come from source to expznsion center in case of R expansion and from expansion center to target in S expansion. I can't make the link between the image/graphic and the formula.
[image]

5. I am completely lost with translation:
   [image]
   Is there an easy way to compute the matrix $(F|G)$ ?
   I don't understand what is done with theses opérator.Here is an example and i have no idea of what the author is doing... If you could give more details please :)[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your first question: That sentence is false; the text itself goes on to state in the very next paragraph under which circumstances the method can be used for singular potentials. The case in which it can't be used is with targets and sources spatially intermingled and a singular potential, because in this case there's no single expansion that will work for all source-target pairs.

On your second question: The aim is not to minimize the computational effort. (If it were, we'd choose $p=0$ and have $0$ computational effort and an estimate of $0$ for the total interaction energy). The aim is to minimize the computational effort given a target accuracy. Depending on circumstances, it may be that using three expansion centres is more efficient in boosting the accuracy than increasing $p$ in the expansion. This will be the case in particular if the sources and/or the targets are located in clusters.

Comment: Joriki, have you any suggestion for the other questions ? Or some documents ?

Comment: No, I don't, and I think it's bad style to add questions to a question like that after it's been answered. You could ask a new question.

Comment: Ok i appologize if it hurts you. I just found  more convenient to put all the questions relative to the tutorial ( (supposing that some other student would be interested by this tutorial) in the same question .

Comment: @laurentpincemaille: That's very kind, thank you, it didn't exactly hurt me :-) I just think that when a question is changed so significantly, without indicating that it was changed significantly, it makes the answer look bad, as if the respondent hadn't addressed most of the question. That's why I wouldn't do that. Another reason is that very few people are going to read through, let alone answer, such a long question with so many subpoints. images and a link to a paper one needs to understand.

Comment: Your point about some other student being interested in the tutorial is a good one, but you can also turn it the other way: If someone else has questions about this tutorial they're not going to be exactly the same set of questions as you have; they may have one or two questions that you had, and some others that you didn't have. Then they shouldn't have to wade through all your questions and all the answers to them to pick out the answers to their questions.

Answer (score 0):

3.[solved]

I can imagine (even if i am not sure it is defined the same way by all specialists) that

- R-expansion stands for **R**eceiver (cause we focused on the configuration where target/receivers are in the target box)
- S-expansion stands for **S**ource (the sources should be in the box!)